# Unit tests in Django: no such table error for class that does not exist

Tags: python, django, sqlite, unit-testing

I have very annoying problem.
If I run my unit tests in Django with `python manage.py jenkins environment=local`
I get error:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: connectors_testex1
```

My test database is sqlite3, real database is postgres.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': CONFIG['database']['db'],
    'USER': CONFIG['database']['user'],
    'PASSWORD': CONFIG['database']['password'],
    'HOST': CONFIG['database']['host'],
    'PORT': CONFIG['database']['port'],
    }
}

if 'test' or 'jenkins' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default'] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'test',
}
```

Problem is that `connectors_testex1` does not exist.

Even if I do

```
grep -r -i "connectors_testex1" /myproject/*
```

it doesn't found anything.

If I use same code on different machine (same git branch) it works normally.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Not sure why you think the class needs to be in your code. Django models are converted into table names using the pattern `<app_name>_<model_name>`, so you presumably have a Connectors app with a TestEx1 model.

Comment: I see. Thanks, the error was somewhere else, but I didn't see it, because I focus on wrong think.